# how to get the dynamic id of simple_form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using `ruby2` and `rails 4`. I have stuck to create my own id for `simple_form`. Every time when I logged in into my project it creates different `id`. Can it possible to get that id?

```
<%= simple_form_for @kyc  do |f| %>
```

Is my code and when I logged in every time I can see the code in inspect element(google chrome)

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/kycs/19" class="simple_form edit_kyc" id="edit_kyc_19" method="post">
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/kycs/20" class="simple_form edit_kyc" id="edit_kyc_20" method="post">
```

Please help me if anybody can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the id of the form is generated by simple_form. If you would like to assign it manually, you can simply try:

```
<%= simple_form_for @kyc, html: { id: :kyc_form } do |f| %>
```

Comment: ya correct absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by using this code.

`<%= simple_form_for @kyc, html: { method: :put, id: :edit_kyc } do |f| %>`

Comment: Did you actually have to use the `method: :put` ?